# My php comment validation function is not working whenever i call it

Tags: php, html

This is a form within a PHP file saved as single.php

```html
<form action="comments.php" method="post" >
                    <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/helpers/formErrors.php"); ?>
                    <input type= "hidden" name="id" value= <?php echo $id; ?> >
                    <textarea rows="4" name="comment"class="text-input contact-input" placeholder="Comment here....."></textarea>
                    <button type='submit' name="postcomment" value="comment" class="btn"> Add Comment</button>

</form>
```

This is also the php file that is receiving the form. comments.php

```php
<?php
include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/helpers/validateComment.php");
$errors = array();

  if(isset($_POST['postcomment'])){ 
    $errors = validateComment($_POST);
     //USE MYSQLI_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING() TO ESCAPE SINGLE QUOTES 
    // AND AGAINST SQL INJECTION 
    $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['id']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['username']);
    $postid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']); 
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['comment']);  
   //prepared statement 
    $sql = $conn->stmt_init();

    $query = "INSERT INTO comments (user_id, post_id, username, comment)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

    if($sql->prepare($query)){
        $sql->bind_param('ssss',$userid,$postid,$username,$comment);

        $sql->execute();
        header("Location:single.php?id=" . $postid); }

}

?>
```

and lastly my validatecomment.php

```php
<?php

function validateComment($comments)
{
$errors = array();

if (empty($comments['comment'])){
    array_push($errors, 'Comment is required!' );
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){     
    array_push($errors, "Sign UP first!");
}
    return $errors;
}

?>
```

I don't understand why the validation is not working. Any help to get this working will highly be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? You never do anything with `$errors` once you call the function.

Comment: when the form is empty, it still submits and when the user is not signed in he is able to add a comment. This is what I want to avoid. @aynber

Comment: So you need to do something with `$errors` after you run the function. See if the array is empty, and if it's not, do something.

Comment: how? i did that in validationComments.php

Comment: You create `$errors` in `validateComment()`, and return it back to `$errors = validateComment($_POST);`. But when you get it back, you do nothing with it, and just continue on with your mysqli functions. You need to actually check `$errors` after that line, and decide what to do **before** you run your queries. It's not going to quit or redirect by itself.

Comment: please can you help me do that because i don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're creating an error array, and doing nothing with it. Basically, you're letting in anyone who knocks whether you want them in or not. What you need to do is actually decide what to do if there are any errors.

```
$errors = validateComment($_POST);
if(!empty($errors)) {
    // Insert code here to redirect, print out errors, whatever you want
} else {
    // And here is where you would put all of your database stuff
   $sql = $conn->stmt_init();

    $query = "INSERT INTO comments (user_id, post_id, username, comment)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

    if($sql->prepare($query)){
        $sql->bind_param('ssss',$userid,$postid,$username,$comment);

        $sql->execute();
        header("Location:single.php?id=" . $postid); }

    }
}
```

Note that I did not use the real_escape_string functions. They are unnecessary when you're using prepared statements.